# Write a procedure to demonstrate that $L$ is recursively enumerable.

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

> Let $L$ be a *recursive* language. Is $L$ *recursively enumerable*? If yes, write a procedure that demonstrate it. If not, write a counterexample.

Given that $L$ is *recursive* we know there exist an algorithm $A$ that for every $w \in \Sigma^*$ decide if it belongs to $L$ or not.

From that follows that $L$ is *recursively enumerable* because we can construct a procedure $P$ that simulates the algorithm $A$ on inputs $w \in L$ and whenever $A$ decide that $w$ is in $L$ then $P$ states it as well; on the other end, when $A$ decide that $w$ in not in $L$ then $P$ simply never terminates.

How would you construct a procedure (in pseudo code) to demonstrate this?

Comment: "L is recursively enumerable" does *not* mean that the "algorithm A that never terminates for every string that do not belong to L.". It only means that the algorithm might not always terminate, and that if it does terminate it must give the right answer.

Comment: Maybe it's a bit unclear. What I'm trying to say is that we can construct a procedure $P$ that simulate $A$ on inputs $w \in \Sigma^*$ and whenever $A$ returns 1 the procedure $P$ returns 1 as well but when $A$ return 0 then the procedure $P$ never terminates. I suppose this is enough to demonstrate that given $L$ *recursive* than $L$ is *recursively enumerable*, isn't it?

Comment: I edited my question, hope its clear now.

Comment: Of course, any details about why my question gets two downvotes could help me understand what's wrong with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details will, of course, depend on your conventions for pseudo-code, but I'd write something like the following (assuming $w$ is given to the algorithm as "input"):

if output(A(input))=yes then (print "yes"; halt)

else while $0=0$ do $x:=0$.